# Access host variable from virtual machine

Tags: reactjs, npm, host

I have a react-app, I set up my app to run on a custom url using the HOST variable when starting the app, something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "HOST=my-local-website.com ..."
}
```

I need to access this url from a windows virtual machine to test it on IE11, before setting up the HOST variable I was able to access it simply from my IP address (192.168.X.XX:3000), having changed the HOST variable this doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know how I can access it from a virtual machine?
Thank you in advance

Comment: and what is the remaining defined as `...` ? it should be something like "strat": HOST=`hostname` react-scripts start

Comment: or all needed values be defined in `.env.development` where react-scripts can access

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest to set environment variables in separate .env file like described in [dicumentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables).
2. In `.env` file set `HOST=my-local-website.com` to change host (it's unclear why official doc recommends prefixing all env variables with `REACT_APP_`)
3. Web site name `my-local-website.com` mapping to IP address of server (`192.168.X.XX:3000` in your case) is done using [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). This relate to networking and not to frameworks you use. So to be able to access your site by name you have to establish mapping between name of the site and IP address

I terms of DNS this mapping will look like

```
my-local-website.com A 192.168.X.XX
```

But for testing purpuses you can use simplified approach (I don't think that you have established DNS server in place). On Windows you can use `hosts` file which is located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` folder. File is named `hosts`. Open it with any text editor (like notepad) and add string

```
192.168.X.XX  my-local-website.com
```

IP address goes first, name last. Dont include port number (:3000) as it not related to DNS. hosts file should be changed on you test (client) PC, not on the PC where your app run.

You may also modify hosts on PC where you app runs to check if host has been configured correctly.

To check that everything is correct you may use `ping` like this

```
ping my-local-website.com
```

IP address should be printed if you configured everything correctly.

4. If you run your app on Windows host there may be problem with firewall configuration. If your app open on the same PC where it is started but not on another PC, most probaly that firewall blocks traffic. It can be WIndows Firewall or antivirus software if you have any.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've done it already but it is still no working. I also tried to use ping, it seems to be okay, but IE11 says "This page can’t be displayed".

Comment: I've tested myself and setting correct env variable in separate `.env` file works fine. I've modified my answer and showed all required steps.

Comment: If I set `REACT_APP_HOST` it doesn't work at all, it still shows localhost as url

Comment: I set up my `REACT_APP_HOST` variable and I had to remove my `HOST` one, now I can access it from windows, but I would also like the when I run `npm run start` it automatically opened my browser with `my-local-website.com:3000` instead of `localhost:3000`

Comment: I've modified answer. I'm able to run react-app on alternative host and this host is set on app start

Comment: I tried it already, if I set both `HOST` and `REACT_APP_HOST`, my react-app starts on `my-local-website.com:3000` but I can't access it from windows or any other devices connected in my network.
If I set only `REACT_APP_HOST` instead, I can access `my-local-website.com:3000` from external devices connected in my network, my react-app works both on `my-local-website.com:3000` and on `localhost:3000`, but it starts on `localhost:3000`.
I hope you get what I mean.